# Error loading Ninject component ICache using Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I'm receiving the following error when executing the web api controller.

I receive this error:

> Error loading Ninject component ICache\r\nNo such component has been
>   registered in the kernel's component container.

The controller I am calling has several Interfaces which are used by the controller.

My controller constructor:

```
private ISDKConfiguration iSDKConfiguration;
private ISDKLogin iSDKLogin;
private ISDKLogout iSDKLogout;
private ISDKRetrieveUserSession iSDKRetrieveUserSession;

public SDKAccountController(ISDKConfiguration sdkConfiguration, ISDKLogin sdkLogin, ISDKLogout sdkLogout, ISDKRetrieveUserSession sdkRetrieveUserSession)
{
    iSDKConfiguration = sdkConfiguration;
    iSDKLogin = sdkLogin;
    iSDKLogout = sdkLogout;
    iSDKRetrieveUserSession = sdkRetrieveUserSession;
}
```

My HTTP Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public SDKUserDTO Login([FromBody]SDKUserDTO sdkUserDTO)
{
    iSDKConfiguration.Load();

    iSDKLogin.SDKUserDTO = sdkUserDTO;
    iSDKLogin.Process();

    iSDKRetrieveUserSession.SDKUserDTO = sdkUserDTO;
    sdkUserDTO = iSDKRetrieveUserSession.Process();

    return sdkUserDTO;
}
```

The NinjectWebCommon.cs which was included when I downloaded the `Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost` nuget package.

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application 
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application. 
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The created kernel. 
    /// </returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);

            System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here! 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">
    /// The kernel. 
    /// </param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ISDKConfiguration>().To<SDKConfiguration>();
        kernel.Bind<ISDKLogin>().To<SDKLogin>();
        kernel.Bind<ISDKLogout>().To<SDKLogout>();
        kernel.Bind<ISDKRetrieveUserSession>().To<SDKRetrieveUserSession>();
    }
}
```

I've edited as per several articles online to include this line of code

```
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

I'm expecting to return the following json.

```
{
  "UserID": "dhu",
  "Password": "password",
  "Identifier": "LoginTestUsingPostman"
}
```

But it's throwing the above exception.

Comment: What exactly throws an error? Which line?

Comment: It doesn't throw the error until the HTTP Post has completed. It shoudl return a JSON value but instead returns the following message.               Error loading Ninject component ICache\r\nNo such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What is the HTTP code returned? Can you debug and step line-by-line to see where the error originates?

Comment: It seems that one (or more) of those SDK* classes depends on ICache, and you did not register in container.